# how to fake authentication in a secured Nancy endpoint

Tags: c#, .net-core, nancy

Currently building a Web API with Nancy in .NET. We had our endpoints secured via a CustomBootStrapper:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : AutofacNancyBootstrapper {
  ...
  pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(SecurityHooks.RequiresAuthentication());
```

However, we wanted to add a Module that was not secured. A simple 'hello world' to verify whether the Web API was starting correctly. So instead we deleted the above line and put in all-except-one of our Module the following:

```
public UsersModule(...) {
  this.RequiresAuthentication();

  Get("/...", async args => {
```

But that gives the problem that each of our unit tests now fail, because obviously now the Module only accepts authenticated calls. And I'm not sure how to 'fake' authenticated calls.

Test Setup:

```
  _sut = new Browser(new ConfigurableBootstrapper(with => {
    var usersModule = new UsersModule(...dataservices);
    with.Module(usersModule);
    with.Dependency<JsonSerializer>(typeof(CamelCasedJsonSerializer));
  }));
```

Actual test:

```
  ... 
  var result = await _sut.Get($"http://localhost:80/api/users/...", with => {
    with.Accept("application/json");
    with.Header("Content-Type", "application/json");
  });
  Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, result.StatusCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current user on the Nancy context in your test setup.

```cs
 with.RequestStartup((container, pipelines, context) => { context.CurrentUser = myTestUser; });
```

This will then cause `this.RequiresAuthentication()` to pass.